# Do amphibians feel pain?

Tags: zoology

It seems strange, but I always hear that toads and frogs don't feel pain.

Is this a true assumption? Do this species can feel pain?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! What research have you done before asking it here?

Comment: Did you read the Wikipedia article... pain in aphibians? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pain_in_amphibians

Comment: Keep in mind that perception of pain is a higher nervous system response that protects the organism from further damage. Amphibians have different responses for protection. Such as receptors for vision, hearing and touch. If they do feel pain they do not seem to indicate that they do so. If a fish on a hook cried out in pain most people would never go fishing. It would seem that pain response is confined to mammals

Comment: Another load on [this](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/60949/do-lobsters-possess-a-nervous-system-to-feel-pain), logically impossible to proove due to problems of qualia. But amphibians are no such magical organism. They are just like any other animal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According the the Wikipedia article, It is widely accepted by scientists that they feel pain, based on their opioid receptors and sensory physiology.

*"Amphibians, particularly anurans, fulfill several physiological and behavioural criteria proposed as indicating that non-human animals may experience pain. These fulfilled criteria include a suitable nervous system and sensory receptors, opioid receptors and reduced responses to noxious stimuli when given analgesics and local anaesthetics, physiological changes to noxious stimuli, displaying protective motor reactions, exhibiting avoidance learning and making trade-offs between noxious stimulus avoidance and other motivational requirements."*

[en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pain_in_amphibians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pain_in_amphibians)